# CSS3 Columns with Vimeo Embed = Blank

Tags: css, iframe, embed, vimeo, multiple-columns

If I set up a layout that uses CSS3 Columns, and try to embed a Vimeo iframe inside that layout, it is presented as a Black box.

Here's a fiddle to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/tMyfa/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">  
<style type='text/css'>
body {
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 2em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<body>
<p>Nullam in dui mauris. Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam.<p>
<p>Nullam in dui mauris. Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam.<p>
<p>Nullam in dui mauris. Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam.<p>
<p>Nullam in dui mauris. Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam.<p>
<p><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/4716148" width="300" height="169" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></p>
<p>Nullam in dui mauris. Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam.<p>  
</body>
</html>
```

If you set the amount of columns to 1, the issue disappears.

Does anyone have any insight on this issue?

Here's an updated fiddle to show better the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/t7AP7/

Comment: Works fine for me on chrome `26.0.1410.43` what browser are you testing it on?

Comment: @KyleNeedham Me too now I'm at home. But not my real version - take a look here - http://cl.ly/O0FW

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
.post_content iframe {
   width: 100% !important;
   height: 200px !important;
}
```

And try setting the width on the iframe like this:

```
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/62257681" 
    width="250" height="150" frameborder="0" 
    webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

Comment: This wouldn't take the media queries into account, ideally, the video needs to be responsive (i.e. 100%)